# How to repeatedly add class to the elements and its descendants resetting at every starting point

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, addclass

I have the following code:

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth'];
$('section').addClass(function(i, c) {
  return classes[i % classes.length];
});

$('section > div').each(function(i, el) {
  $(this).addClass(classes[i  % classes.length]);
});
```

This creates the following for example:

```
<section class="first">
    <div class"first"></div>
        <div class"first"></div>
        <div class"second"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<section class="second">
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>
<section class="third">
    <div class="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the loop to reset each div.  So for example the children of each section would start over with a class of first, instead of picking up where the previous child class left off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth'];
$('section').addClass(function (i, c) {
     $(this).children('div').addClass(function (i) { //Do an addClass for children divs
        return classes[i % classes.length]; //return the class based on its index
    });
    return classes[i % classes.length]; //return the class for section based on its index
});
```

Issue in your snippet is that `'section > div'` selector will return all the divs in all the sections as a collection and `i` (index) will be the index of the item in the collection not the index of the element with respective to its siblings, So you dont see it getting reseted.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nYt5F/)**

As a generic approach if you want to go more deep adding classes it children try this way:

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth'];
$('section').addClass(addClassToChild);


function addClassToChild(i) {
    $(this).children().addClass(addClassToChild);
    return classes[i % classes.length];
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d4X4u/)**

For an input:

```
<section>Section1
    <div>S1 D1
        <div>S1 D1 D1</div>
        <div>S1 D1 D2</div>
    </div>
    <div>S1 D2</div>
</section>
<section>Section2
    <div>S2 D1
        <div>S2 D1 D1</div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>Section3
    <div>S3 D1
        <div>S3 D1 D1</div>
        <div>S3 D1 D2</div>
    </div>
    <div>S3 D2</div>
</section>
```

Will output as:

```
 <section class="first">Section1
    <div class="first">S1 D1
        <div class="first">S1 D1 D1</div>
        <div class="second">S1 D1 D2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">S1 D2</div>
</section>
<section class="second">Section2
    <div class="first">S2 D1
        <div class="first">S2 D1 D1</div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="third">Section3
    <div class="first">S3 D1
        <div class="first">S3 D1 D1</div>
        <div class="second">S3 D1 D2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">S3 D2</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is excellant

if i wanted to go as far as continuing this, for example, the childrens "children" so to speak.  Could I include that function inside the $(this).childre...etc?

so section > div > div if that helps clear it up.  Thank you again.  This is greatly appreciated

@PSL

Comment: @user3109293 Yes you could do. Infact you can remove the selector `div` inside children and write a common function which returns the class based on index and use it as callback.

Comment: Could you possible link me to a reference if you have one? Im definitely going to try that out as it would completely fix it. 

Either way, thanks again for this, im already using it, just trying to figure out that callback now.

Comment: This some it up completely.  I was hoping for just a hint, thank you again.  Hope this helps others out

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the index of the divs from the child set, where all the child divs are arranged sequentially.

Instead find the index of the div based on its siblings using .index()

```
$('section > div').each(function(i, el) {
  $(this).addClass(classes[$(this).index()  % classes.length]);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VbT32/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate variable that can be incremented and reset on it's own, the typical letter to use is `k` after `i` is used.

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth'];
$('section').addClass(function(i, c) {
  return classes[i % classes.length];
});

$('section > div').each(function(k, el) {
  $(this).addClass(classes[k  % classes.length]);
});
```

Comment: variable shouldn't matter...`$.each` creates a a closure

Answer (score 0):

Can look for the div within the first loop, so indexing of the chidlren is based on it's siblings, not the hole collection in page

```
$('section').addClass(function(i, c) {
  $(this).children().addClass(function(idx){
       return classes[idx  % classes.length];
   })
  return classes[i % classes.length];  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably isn't the answer you were looking for but depending on your browser requirements you can look into just using CSS for this.

```
section:nth-child(1)
section:nth-child(2)
section:nth-child(3)

div:nth-child(1)
div:nth-child(2)
div:nth-child(3)
```

Here is a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/umufAGaC/1/edit?html,css,js,output